# Using for loop to iterate number of occurrences in ta.valuewhen

Tags: loops, iteration, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to set up a table with a flexible amount of rows depending on the number of trades that happened within a time window. The variable `TradeNumber` holds the number of trades. My plan was using a for loop to create the necessary amount of rows:

```
for i = 1 to TradeNumber
        table.cell(statsTable, 0, i, str.tostring(ta.valuewhen(BreakNegative, TradeNumber, i)))
```

As you can see, I'd like to display the value of `TradeNumber` in each row. To obtain this value I'm using `ta.valuewhen` with `BreakNegative` as the condition and `i` as iterator.

I just realized from the error message that `i` cannot be used since it's a series int and a simple int is needed for the requested number of the occurrence.

Does anyone here know a workaround that allows me to still use a for loop in order to create the table rows? Or will I have to manually create the rows and insert simple int number for the occurrences of `ta.valuewhen`?

Thanks for your input!

For better context see the entire script below:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © bimsbrohm

//@version=5
indicator("Backtest Snippet", overlay = true, max_labels_count=500, max_bars_back = 5000)

var float MaxProfit_USD = na
var float MaxProfit_Perc = na
var TradeNumber = 0
var bool InTrade = na
var float EntryPrice = na
var float highest = na
var float lowest = na
var float NumberShares = na
var float TradeLength = na
var string TradeDir = na
var int lookbackCrossUp = na
var int lookbackCrossDown = na
var int barIndexCrossUp = na 
var int barIndexCrossDown = na 

// Rounding Function
RoundDown(number, decimals) =>
    factor = math.pow(10, decimals)
    math.floor(number * factor) / factor


// DATE RANGE FILTERING
DateFilter = input.bool(true, '═════════════ Date Range Filtering', group='Date')
i_startTime = input.time(defval=timestamp('01 Jan 2023 09:30 +0000'), title='Start', group='Date')
i_endTime = input.time(defval=timestamp('31 Dec 2023 16:00 +0000'), title='Ende', group='Date')
TradeDateIsAllowed() =>
    DateFilter ? time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime : true

Equity = 10000

// Entry Signal: MA-Cross
MA1 = ta.ema(close, 10)
MA2 = ta.ema(close, 50)

plot(MA1, color=color.red, linewidth = 3)
plot(MA2, color=color.green, linewidth = 3)

CrossUp = ta.crossover(MA1, MA2) and TradeDateIsAllowed()
CrossDown = ta.crossunder(MA1, MA2) and TradeDateIsAllowed()

// CALCULATIONS

if CrossUp or CrossDown
    TradeNumber := TradeNumber + 1
    InTrade := true
    EntryPrice := close
    NumberShares := (Equity/EntryPrice)
    if CrossUp
        TradeDir := 'Long'
    else if CrossDown
        TradeDir := 'Short'
    
if InTrade
    lookbackCrossUp := ta.barssince(CrossUp)
    lookbackCrossDown := ta.barssince(CrossDown)
    barIndexCrossUp := bar_index - lookbackCrossUp
    barIndexCrossDown := bar_index - lookbackCrossDown
    TradeLength := TradeDir == 'Long' ? lookbackCrossUp : TradeDir == 'Short' ? lookbackCrossDown : na
    if lookbackCrossUp > 0 
        highest := ta.highest(lookbackCrossUp)
    else if lookbackCrossDown > 0
        lowest := ta.lowest(lookbackCrossDown)
    MaxProfit_USD := (highest * NumberShares) - (EntryPrice * NumberShares)
    MaxProfit_USD := RoundDown(MaxProfit_USD,2)
    MaxProfit_Perc := ((highest - EntryPrice)/EntryPrice) * 100
    MaxProfit_Perc := RoundDown(MaxProfit_Perc,1)

BreakNegative = ta.crossunder(close, EntryPrice)
if BreakNegative
    InTrade := false

var table statsTable = table.new(position = position.bottom_right, columns = 4, rows = 100, frame_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0), frame_width = 2, border_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0), border_width = 1)

// Horizontal headers
table.cell(table_id = statsTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = 'Trade Number', text_halign = text.align_left)
table.cell(table_id = statsTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = 'Trade Length', text_halign = text.align_left)
table.cell(table_id = statsTable, column = 2, row = 0, text = 'Max Profit in %', text_halign = text.align_left)
table.cell(table_id = statsTable, column = 3, row = 0, text = 'Max Profit in USD', text_halign = text.align_left)

for i = 1 to TradeNumber
    table.cell(statsTable, 0, i, str.tostring(ta.valuewhen(BreakNegative, TradeNumber, 1)))
    table.cell(statsTable, 1, i, str.tostring(ta.valuewhen(BreakNegative, TradeLength, 1)))
    table.cell(statsTable, 2, i, str.tostring(ta.valuewhen(BreakNegative, MaxProfit_Perc, 1)))
    table.cell(statsTable, 3, i, str.tostring(ta.valuewhen(BreakNegative, MaxProfit_USD, 1)))
```